# Prevent adding duplicate values html table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one HTML table and I don't want the value of 2nd column to repeat in the grid.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('#tb_cartTable tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
    $ele=$(this).text();
if($ele==$productCode)
    {
        flag="x";
        return false;
    }
});

if($rowCounter>0 && flag=="x")
{
    alert("Duplicate");
}
else
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: is there any error ? could you please initialize a complete example with jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: please post the whole code... atleast those where you are defining $productCode,$rowcounter, flag

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rinuthomas90/ZXvQb/            Here is my requirement the when I click add button, values are appending to my jsp page.. We can't accept duplicate values to table. Same product code should not be added to the table..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rinuthomas90/ZXvQb/             when I click add button, values are appending to my jsp page.. We can't accept duplicate value(product code) to table. How to check the added value and the value which I am going to add .. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way will be to "map" the text of the cells into a JavaScript complex array having the text as key, then compare the amount of keys to amount of cells. If more cells than keys it means there are cells with the same text.

Code for this:

```
var allCells = $('#tb_cartTable tr td:nth-child(2)');
var textMapping = {};
allCells.each(function() {
    textMapping[$(this).text()] = true;
});

var count = 0;
for (var text in textMapping)
    count++;

if (count !== allCells.length) {
    alert("found duplicate values");
} else {
    alert("no duplicates found");
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/vCMym/1/).

Note the above is case sensitive: if there is a cell with "hello" and cell with "Hello" those will be considered different and it will think there are no duplicates. If case doesn't matter fix is simple case of changing the line to:

```
textMapping[$(this).text().toLowerCase()] = true;
```

[Updated test case](http://jsfiddle.net/vCMym/2/) where it ignores case.

In your specific case you can store all the added values in plain array then check the array using the jQuery `inArray()` method:

```
var $addedProductCodes = [];
$("#button_addItem").click(function(event)
{
    $("span.errorText").remove();
    $(".errorField").addClass("notErrorField");

       //Change background color of textbox to normal
       $("#frmRegisterForm :input[type='text']").attr('class','notErrorField');
    $hasError = false;
    $ele = $(event.target);
    if($ele.is("input[type=button]"))
    {    
        $td_productCode1=$("#td_productCode1").val();
        var index = $.inArray($td_productCode1, $addedProductCodes);
        if (index >= 0) {
            alert("You already added this product code in line #" + (index + 1));
        } else {
            $text_productDescription= $("#text_productDescription").val();
            $text_basicDealerPrice = $("#text_basicDealerPrice").val();
            $('#table_viewContent').append("<tr><td>"+$text_productDescription+"</td><td>"+$td_productCode1+"</td><td><td>"+$text_basicDealerPrice+"</td><td><input type='button'  name='deleteRow' id='btn_deleteRow' value='Delete' id='deleteItem' class='deleteItem button-red'></td></tr>");        
            $addedProductCodes.push($td_productCode1);
        }
    }
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXvQb/1/) where adding same product code will give alert and won't insert.

Comment: I ve three text fieds and one add button. Whenever I click on add button values append below in the table. I want to prevent duplicate values while adding data to the tables... Means I ve to compare the added values and the value which im going to add..

Comment: Sorry I answered your direct question and posted code to detect duplicate values in the cells. If you reach the "found duplicate values" simply don't add to the table, really can't see where you are stuck.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rinuthomas90/ZXvQb/             when I click add button, values are appending to my table(the next line).. We can't accept duplicate value(product code) to table. How to check the added value and the value which I am going to add .. Please help me

Comment: Hi Shadow wizrd,Initially my table will be empty. I willbe having only some text fields and button.. When I fill values and click on add , values are appending to the next line.. When I add 2nd time I wanted to check the column values are repeating or not

Comment: Cheers, you can mark this answer as correct by ticking the empty V icon to the left, this way the question will be marked as "resolved".

Comment: :( **I am facing small issue again**
[http://jsfiddle.net/rinuthomas90/ZXvQb/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/rinuthomas90/ZXvQb/3/) Check here
I ve added two different products and deleted one from the table, then I am trying to add same product(which is deleted) again. When I try add the same product after deleting from the table, it is throwing error saying it is already added.Plase help(jquery 1.8.3)

Comment: I fixed it with `$addedProductCodes.splice($td_productCode1);` . Is this good practice ? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rinuthomas90/ZXvQb/4/)

Comment: @Rinu cheers, but your fix wasn't correct, you removed the whole array. You need to remove one specific item. Also note that `.live()` is deprecated and not working anymore as of jQuery 1.9 so you better use `.on()` instead. [here is updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXvQb/5/) with everything I mentioned fixed. (also in your own fix you always took the last added product code instead of the product code relevant to the row deleted, fixed that as well :))